# java neo4j rest how to get the url of a created node

Tags: java, rest, neo4j

I am creating some nodes within a transaction in neo4j using the rest api. After all nodes have been created (typically between 3 and 5 in one transaction), I have to create some relationships between them. To do this I need, of course the location of the nodes, and this is the source of my problem. I can't figure out how to get this location.

According to documentation, I should be able to get the location of a node from the response-object, after creating the node, like so:

```
nodeLocation = response.getLocation();
```

But in a transaction, this of course returns the url of the transaction:

```
http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/108
```

Then I thought, if I query for the just created node, maybe in that response I can find the location. Again, according to documentation, the node location should be presented in the json-structure extensions in the field self.

```
 "self" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/357",
```

But my response to the query does not seem to contain an extension structure.

This is the query I'm using:

```
 {"statements": [ {"statement": "MATCH (p:POST {sn_id: 'TW', id: '536982477664190465'} ) RETURN p"} ] }
```

I send it to the open transaction, and I get this back:

```
 GET to http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/108 returned status code 200, returned data: {"commit":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/108/commit","results":[{"columns":["p"],"data":[]}],"transaction":{"expires":"Mon, 24 Nov 2014 20:40:34 +0000"},"errors":[]}
```

Just for completeness, this is the code for my query:

```
 String payload = "{\"statements\": "
                + "[ "
                    + "{\"statement\": "
                        + "\"MATCH (p:POST {sn_id: 'TW', id: '536982477664190465'} ) RETURN p\""
                    + "} "
                + "] "
            + "}";


        logger.trace("sending cypher {} to endpoint {}", payload, endpointLoc);
        WebResource resource = Client.create().resource( endpointLoc );

        ClientResponse response = resource
                .accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
                .type( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
                .entity( payload )
                .get(ClientResponse.class);
                //.post( ClientResponse.class );

        String responseEntity = response.getEntity(String.class).toString();
        int responseStatus = response.getStatus();
        logger.trace("GET to {} returned status code {}, returned data: {}",
                endpointLoc, responseStatus,
                responseEntity);

        JSONParser reponseParser = new JSONParser();
            Object responseObj = reponseParser.parse(responseEntity);
            JSONObject jsonResponseObj = responseObj instanceof JSONObject ?(JSONObject)   responseObj : null;
            if(jsonResponseObj == null)
                throw new ParseException(0, "returned json object is null");

            String result = (String) jsonResponseObj.get("results").toString();
            logger.trace("result is {} ", result);

            String error = (String) jsonResponseObj.get("errors").toString();
```

Am I missing something? Do I need to use a special call?

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance,

Christian

Comment: Your MATCH query returned no data.  Maybe that's because there aren't any matches in the database.  Also, when you do getLocation() on response, I'm afraid you might be getting the URL of where you POSTed the query.  "Response" here is the HTTP response coming back from the server, right and not the JSON response payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you need the node-URL for?

That's the *old* RESTful representation. You can either get it by using the old HTTP endpoint `/db/data/cypher` or better by specifying the (very verbose) [`resultDataContents` type `REST`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-execute-statements-in-an-open-transaction-in-rest-format-for-the-return)
You can also specify other types like "row" and "graph" in parallel.

```
 {"statements": [ 
   {"statement": "MATCH (p:POST {sn_id: 'TW', id: '536982477664190465'} ) RETURN p",
    "resultDataContents":["REST"]} 
 ] }
```